# Fetch data extension objects that has been changed since a specific date

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, lastmodifieddate

How can I fetch data extension objects that has been changed since a specific date?

I'm trying to query DataExtensionObject with a simple filter that checks if the property ModifiedDate is greater than a given timestamp, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: The Filter Property 'ModifiedDate' is not a retrievable property.

Comment: Hi Viki, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Thanks are not necessary, and "Can anyone advise?" is just a yes/no question whose answer doesn't give you any information. That is why I have removed that content from your post.

Comment: It does appear that ModifiedDate is a property available to the DataExtensionObject via API/SDK - perhaps you could show the relevant code and we can better help find what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no such attribute exists for Data Extension rows.

There are some some that are barely documented -- like [**_CustomObjectKey**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) -- but that's it.

Sure would be nice for building churn reports.